# C runtime and date command on cygwin

Tags: c, date, unix

Background

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 Owner-PC 1.7.34(0.285/5/3) 2015-02-04 12:14 x86_64 Cygwin
```

PS: just updated Cygwin 15 days ago.  Should be razor close to current.

```
$ date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.23
Packaged by Cygwin (8.23-4)
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie.
```

Extracted from man date page on cygwin:

```
 %c     locale's date and time (e.g., Thu Mar  3 23:05:25 2005)
```

output from C runtime (dtime is tiny piece of code):

```
$ ./dtime -f "%c"
Tue Feb  5 17:04:45 2030
```

Looks good to me...
To avert questions like: what does the code look like:

```
strcpy(p->fmt, "%c");
.... 
strftime(tmp, 80, p->fmt, localtime(&lt)); 
printf("%s\n", tmp);
```

dtime and other time routines I wrote in the C library behave as expected per standards.  No problem.

On the other hand the date command is not correct AFAICT:

```
Owner@Owner-PC ~
$ date
Sun, Feb 22, 2015 11:41:44 AM

Owner@Owner-PC ~
$ date +%c
Sun, Feb 22, 2015 11:41:55 AM
```

The second line of output does not match the man page - or standards, I believe.

Question:
A bug? Something else I am missing?

Edit: per suggestion quote the format string. No.  That is only need if there are white spaces in the format

```
Owner@Owner-PC ~
$ date '+%c'
Sun, Feb 22, 2015  3:13:51 PM
```

Comment: It looks like you are using an unix-ish shell, but if not argument corruption could be an issue (and even so there may be quirks).  You could try stracing the date program, or simply find and examine its source code.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - Probably not.  This is just the adhoc use of the date command from scripts and the command line.  Someone with the exact same version of Cygwin date should try it if you believe there is some intrinsic error like that.  And. I was after a shortcut.  Have you seen GNU date source?  Got a few spare days to read and assimilate? If nobody actually knows I'll look at the code.  Using bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems related to the locale settings.  Your C program uses the C locale by default, date will behave according to the environment variables LANG, LC_TIME and LC_ALL.  What are the values of these variables ?  Can you test this:

```
LC_ALL="C" date '+%c'
```

Comment: I found that the locale was scrambled, completely reinstalled cygwin and all is much better now.  I thought of something similar earlier, but yours is an answer, too.

Comment: I guess this answer was useful, albeit the hint was really in the man page ;-)